# Override layer property from UIView to subclass UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am converting some Swift code to Objective C. not much familiar with Swift syntax.

```
override var layer: CAShapeLayer {
    get {
        return super.layer as! CAShapeLayer
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to override this property in objective C.

I tried this 
in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) CAShapeLayer *layer;
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize layer;
```

but it seems to not work. There is no error but the code is not executing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do now is just implement the getter for the layer property:

```
-(CAShapeLayer *)layer
{
   return (CAShapeLayer *)super.layer
}
```